# Get image URL for a given Google Place ID in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I have a `GMSPlace` object and I want to get the image URL for that place but the Google Places SDK doesn't seem to allow for that.

`loadImageForMetadata` only returns an object of type `UIImage`. I don't need the image just the URL.

How do I find the image url for a given Google Place ID? Here's a class I've written to help me work with the Google Places SDK:

```
import Foundation
import GooglePlaces

class GoogleImageService: NSObject {
    class func loadFirstPhotoForPlace(placeID: String) {
        GMSPlacesClient.shared().lookUpPhotos(forPlaceID: placeID) { (photos, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            if let firstPhoto = photos?.results[0] {
                self.loadImageForMetadata(photoMetadata: firstPhoto, placeID: placeID)
            }
        }
    }

    class func loadImageForMetadata(photoMetadata: GMSPlacePhotoMetadata, placeID: String) {
        GMSPlacesClient.shared().loadPlacePhoto(photoMetadata, callback: { (photo, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            // photo parameter in the closure is an UIImage, not helpful
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/photos

Comment: @Adrian anything specific you'd like to highlight in the page? I've read that page like 20 times

Comment: Oops...didn't RTFQ thoroughly. you're looking for the URL, not the image. I haven't worked with that framework before, but you might right click on the method and dig around for clues how it gets the URL.